# Simple Java program Arraylist

Tags: java, input, arraylist

I'm trying to make a simple program that demonstrates the use of ArrayLists of objects. I want to be able to input the details to be stored in the objects as well as searching for and printing objects.

I'm doing it on Students I have my Student class made and I have started my studentTest class but I'm looking for help with input to start with.

This is what I have so far:

```
package student;

public class Student {

    private String studentName;
    private String studentNo;
    private String email;
    private int year;

    public Student() {
      /**studentName = null;
        *studentNo = null;
        *email = null;
        *year = -1;
        */
    }

    public Student(String nName, String nNum, String nEmail, int nYr) {
        this.studentName = nName;
        this.studentNo = nNum;
        this.email = nEmail;
        this.year = nYr;
    }

    public void setStudentName(String newStudentName) {
        studentName = newStudentName;
    }

    public void setStudentNo(String newStudentNo) {
        studentNo = newStudentNo;
    }

    public void setEmail(String newEmail) {
        email = newEmail;
    }

    public void setYear(int newYear) {
        year = newYear;
    }

    public String getStudentName() {
        return studentName;
    }

    public String getStudentNo() {
        return studentNo;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }


    }
}

package student;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class studentTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        Student student1 = new Student();
        Student student2 = new Student();
        Student student3 = new Student();
        Student student4 = new Student();
        Student student5 = new Student();


    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Rob, what's the question you're asking?

Comment: So far good, now you need to read this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Comment: ...and decide what features you want to provide.  What exactly do you want to do with the ArrayList?

Comment: Is it a requirement of the assignment to actually get input from the keyboard for this test?  In the "real world" you wouldn't want to do this because it would make your tests a pain to run, and they'd be dependent on the user providing the same input each time.  Is it allowed to hard-code the test data?  If so, you should.  Then you can hard code known problem cases to ensure that you have properly addressed those cases.

Comment: It's not for tests it is just to get the Student info. I'm a little lost on how to do the arraylist and then input each individual Student.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You may want to update the main method as below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter number of students");
    int countStudents = input.nextInt();

    for(int i=0; i< countStudents; i++){
          Student student = new Student();
          System.out.println("Enter details for student"+i);

          System.out.println("Enter name");
          student.setStudentName(input.next()); 

          System.out.println("Enter Number");
          student.setStudentNo(input.next()); 

          System.out.println("Enter email");
          student.setEmail(input.next()); 

          System.out.println("Enter year");
          student.setYear(input.nextInt()); 
          students.add(student);
    }
    //Your list of students is populated now
}
```

Comment: @Nagative Voter: Please leave some comments to help understand what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the document for [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html).

From the code that you have done so far in `studentTest` it looks like you are taking all the inputs from the user.

You basically need to input all data in a loop:

```
// create ArrayList
for (int i=0; i < 5; i++) {
   String studentName = input.nextLine();
   ....

   Student student = new Student();
   student.setStudentName();
   ...

   // add student to arraylist
}
```

I think that you will benefit from filling in the bits I've left out.

Answer (score 0):

I think he just want to populate the Student class
something like this.

```
 while(true){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    Student student1 = new Student();
    int year= input.nextInt();
    String studentName=input.nextLine();
    studentNo=input.nextLine();
    String email=input.nextLine();

    student1.setStudentName(studentName);
    student1.setStudentNo(studentNo);
    student1.setEmail(email);
    student1.setYear(year) 

    int year= input.nextInt();
    String studentName=input.nextLine();
    studentNo=input.nextLine();
    String email=input.nextLine();



      break; // at the last position
      }
```